# Why the validation errors are not appearing in the "#response" div? (instead appears 422 Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a multi-step form using jQuery anad AJAX and I want to valdiate each step with an ajax post request.But Im getting this error when "go to step 2" is clicked and there are validation errors:

```
jquery.min.js:4
POST http://store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 
422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

But what I have to have when there is a validation error is show in the div "#response" the validation errors.  Do you know why this is not working?

**Relevant code for the question:**

I have a PaymentController there is the storeUserInfo() Method that is the method for the step 1:

```
 public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'buyer_name' => 'required|max:1|string',
            'buyer_surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_email' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'name_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'country_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ]);

        if($validator->passes())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'success'
            ], 200);
        }
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors =  json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $errors
        ], 422);
    }
```

Route:

```
  Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);
```

// step 1 and step 2 html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <div id="response"></div> <!-- div to show errors -->
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix tabs hide" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <form method="post">
            <h6>Payment method</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentmethod1" value="option1" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">payment method 1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="credit_card" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">Stripe</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step">
                Go back to step 2
            </button>
            <button type="button"  data-nexttab="#step3" href="#step3"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn ml-2 next-step">
                Go to step 3
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    // ajax in payment.blade.php
    $('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{    route('products.storeUserInfo',compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                setTimeout(function () {

                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '';
                $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                });

                $('#response').show().html(errorsHtml);
            }
        });

        });
    });
```

// ajax in payment.blade.php

```
$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{    route('products.storeUserInfo',compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                setTimeout(function () {

                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '';
                $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                });

                $('#response').show().html(errorsHtml);
            }
        });

        });
    });
```

Comment: What error appeares in network tab ? What do you see in console when you console log custom_form.serialize()? Did you import Validator facade at he top ?

Comment: Writing "console.log(custom_form.serialize())" in the console it appaers:
VM2208:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: custom_form is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13".

Comment: Try sending your data one by one by $('input').Val() because I think that the problem is with data sent.

Comment: Thanks I can have "var buyer_name = $('[name="buyer_name"]').val();", and the some for the other fields but then how to add all this fields to ajax data option?

Comment: Data: { name: value, name: value }

Comment: Thanks but also dont works it appears "419 (unknown status)".

Comment: We're moving forward :p I need more info about an error you are getting

Comment: It also appears: "{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you have to add value[0] to your errors instead of value. try this out maybe it can help:

```
    error: function (data) {
    var json = data.responseJSON;
    if (json) {
       var errors = json.errors;
        var errorsHtml = '<ul class="list-group">';
        $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
        errorsHtml += '<li class="list-group-item 
        alert alert-danger">' + value[0] + '</li>';
    });
    errorHtml+='</ul>';
    $('#response').show().html(errorsHtml);
    }
 }
```

Change your controller function to this:

```
 public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

    $this->validate($request,[

        'buyer_name' => 'required|max:1|string',
        'buyer_surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'buyer_email' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'name_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
        'country_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
   ]);

    return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue.

Comment: As you mentioned you get 422 error. It means you have validation errors. So maybe you have a mistake in another part of your code. I checked my own code which works for me as I expect. So please console log the errorsHtml after $.each and see whats it content.

Comment: And please replace exactly the code above with your error function

Comment: I found out that you insert every error in a separate ul. I don't think that it's the main reason but I fixed it.

Comment: The console.log(errorsHtml) shows "<ul class="list-group">".

Comment: Just the ul? how about the li?

Comment: The <li> dont appear in the console.log(errorsHtml), just that ul.

Comment: It appears "<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert - danger">The buyer name may not be greater than 1 characters.</li>".  With "                                console.log(errorsHtml);
" after "                                errorsHtml += '<li class="list-group-item alert alert - danger">' + value[0] + '</li>';
".

Comment: But before that console.log it appears "POST http://store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 422 (Unprocessable Entity)"

Comment: Change your controller as I edited and try one more time

Comment: Like that same issue, first appears "POST store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 422 (Unprocessable Entity)" and then "
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ registration:525
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
registration:543 <ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert - danger">The buyer name may not be greater than 1 characters.</li>".

Comment: If you see all <li>'s and error messages when you log it to console it means that everything is ok. But maybe jquery cannot find your #response div or maybe you've hidden it with css,

Comment: The errors appear in the "#response" div but it appears also that error "POST store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 422 (Unprocessable Entity)".

Comment: No problem the first line shows the xhr request and certainly it changes to red and after that we see console log result

Comment: Of course it's normal my friend. Visit this website which I've built http://boustanico.com/contact-us and watch the console when you submit the form blank.